# date not updating in android app when left open overnight

Tags: android, datepickerdialog, android-date

I am having an issue with one of the apps I am working on. The app has a DatePickerDialog in it with a calendar icon in the ActionBar. I am setting it up like so...

MainActivity.java

```
//...
private final Calendar myCal = Calendar.getInstance();

private final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDateSet(DatePicker picker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    myCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, i);
    myCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, i1);
    myCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, i2);
    if(myCal.getTimeInMillis() < minCalendarDateAllowed) {
      //show toast.
    } else {
      pageDateMillis = myCal.getTimeInMillis();
      updateToolbar();
    }
  }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
  super.onCreate(savedState);
  myCal.setTimeInMillis(pageDateMillis);
  dialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
    dateListener,
    myCal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
    myCal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
    myCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
  dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
  ...
  // get start date from SharedPreferences (stored as long)
  minCalendarDateAllowed = startDate;
  dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(startDate);
  ...
}

// UPDATED POST TO SHOW THIS FUNCTION
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
public void setupToolbar() {
  //setup toolbar
  ...
  myCal.setTimeInMillis(new Date().getTime());
  pageDateMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
  //get startDate from SharedPreferences (stored as long)
  dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(startDate);
  dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
  minCalendarDateAllowed = startDate;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  int id = item.getItemId();
  if(id == android.R.id.home) {
    //Calendar icon is taking the place of the home icon
    if(startDate == 0L) {
      //get start date from SharedPreferences (stored as long)
    }
    dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
    dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(startDate);
    dialog.show();
    return true;
  }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

It all works great, unless you open up the app, then while the app is running, turn the screen off, do not touch the phone until tomorrow, then try to use the app. when you click the calendar icon the date picker dialog shows up as expected but it still shows yesterdays date as the current date and todays date is not selectable. If you leave the app app and come back to it it works again as expected. I am not quite sure how to go about fixing this issue because I have never left an app open and active overnight I thought that adding the setMaxDate to a new Date() when the button is clicked it should handle that scenario, but it's not. The date picker shows yesterday as current and today as unselectable.

Answer (score 0):

Put DatePickerDialog in onResume().

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    //your code here
}
```

Whenever you switch the app or lock the phone onPause() is called and when you again open your app, onResume() is called.

Activity Lifecycle: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I do have the onResume function defined with the updates there as well. I will update my post to reflect. I apologize and thank you.